# comparing set of nodes in two xml file with Ant

Tags: xml, ant, compare, xmlnode

I am trying to compare two XML files with Ant. My intention is to compare specific nodes inside those XML files rather than complete XMLs.

Please let me know if any one has encountered this and was able to fix.

Answer (score 0):

What you try to say??

I think you want to compare values like this:
C# Code for compare values in two xml files.

```
string item1;
string item2 ;   
XmlDocument xmlDoc1 = new XmlDocument();
XmlDocument xmlDoc2 = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc1.Load(Server.MapPath("Document1.xml"));
xmlDoc2.Load(Server.MapPath("Document2.xml"));
XmlNodeList Nodelist1 = xmlDoc1.SelectNodes("//DataRows/DocumentElement");
XmlNodeList Nodelist2 = xmlDoc2.SelectNodes("//DataRows/DocumentElement");
foreach (XmlNode node1 in Nodelist1)
            {
                item1 = node["itemName"].InnerText;
                }
foreach (XmlNode node2 in Nodelist2)
            {
                item2 = node["itemName"].InnerText;
                }
if(item1 ==item2)
{
//to do
}
```

Hope it work will.

Answer (score 0):

Ant cannot do this in a meaningful way.

You can compare XML with [XMLUnit](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need [XML Task](http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/).  I use it for things like editing XML configuration files (Tomcat server.xml, specifically), but you can just as easily use it to hack apart XML based on XPath statements and compare the contents of nodes.